# Seating Plan generator in React

Tags: reactjs

I looking for a seating plan generator to add to my site. My seating information needs to come as an object. And I want to render the seating plan according to that. Is it possible to render something like below?
[image: seatplan]

I have tried react seat picker too. but spaces between seats are not taken

[image: seat picker screen]

[image]

Comment: Yes, it is possible. Give sample data and what you have tried already

Comment: I tried https://codesandbox.io/s/nwk09p7o34?fontsize=14 but space between seats are not taken.

Comment: null in your data represents a seating space, isn't it? what is the actual problem?

Comment: for seats not shown like in D row 4th seat, it should be another value in your data like notUsableSeat: true flag

Comment: actually, null is not taking. that's the problem. will update in the question

Comment: in your sandbox, it is working fine. seems like your working setup has some CSS class called "blank" with some other styles

Comment: this is what I get when try on my project

Comment: @AmilaSenadheera any updates??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the issue was in my CSS file commenting the blank attribute will fix the error.

```
div.seat {
    background-color: green;
  }
  
  div.seat--reserved {
    background-color: rgb(209, 7, 7);
  }
  
  div.seat--selected {
    background-color: blue;
  }
  
  .seat-picker {
    margin: auto;
  }
  
  .seat-picker__row {
  }
  
  .seat-picker__row__number {
  }
  
  /* div.blank {
    display: none;
  } */
```